# AlertDialog in arrayAdapter not working

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, android-alertdialog, android-context

I'm trying to get my alertDialog working in an arrayAdapter. This is how my function looks like.

```
   @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final Noodnummers currentNoodnummer = noodnummers.get(position);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View rowView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        TextView txt_noodnummer_name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_noodnummer_name);
        txt_noodnummer_name.setText(currentNoodnummer.naam);

        TextView txt_noodnummer_telefoon = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_noodnummer_telefoon);
        txt_noodnummer_telefoon.setText(Html.fromHtml(currentNoodnummer.telefoonNummer));
        txt_noodnummer_telefoon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
                try {

                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                            .setTitle("")
                            .setMessage("Bent u zeker dat u" + currentNoodnummer.telefoonNummer + "wilt bellen?")
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    // continue with delete
                                    String uri = currentNoodnummer.telefoonNummer;
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
                                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    // do nothing
                                }

                            })
                            .show();


                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
                    Log.e("genkonstage", "Call failed", activityException);
                }

            }
        });



        return rowView;
    }
```

The first problem is, that  `new AlertDialog.Builder(this)` is given me an error on the word `this`. Then I found that I maybe should use a context. But when I say `new AlertDialog.Builder(context)` I get no error but when I click the app crashes.

Can someone help me with this?

**EDIT**

```
06-18 10:56:20.689  12980-12980/be.appmax.genkOnStage          E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:571)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:246)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
        at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:951)
        at be.appmax.genkOnStage.adapters.NoodnummersArrayAdapter$1.onClick(NoodnummersArrayAdapter.java:57)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Creation of arrayAdapter inside `NoodnummersActivity`

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewNoodnummers);
//addList(noodnummersArrayList, listView);
NoodnummersArrayAdapter adapter = new NoodnummersArrayAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.noodnummers_list, noodnummersArrayList);

// fill the listview with adapter.
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listView);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Never" use getBaseContext()! [From a Google Engineer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/2-XxjT26mqk/2xZfYx-YS_oJ)

Try with `NoodnummersActivity.this`

```
NoodnummersArrayAdapter adapter = new NoodnummersArrayAdapter(NoodnummersActivity.this, R.layout.noodnummers_list, noodnummersArrayList);
```

and then try with

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
```

---

By the way, I suggest at the beginning of your activity to define a private field with the context. I found this suggestion here somewhere and I find it awesome:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private Context context = MyActivity.this;
}
```

in this way you can use "context" without any worries.

Comment: probably he already does it, since he is using context with the inflater

Comment: you don't need that, since the context passed in the constructor is available through getContext()

Comment: Hm, you're right. It's strange btw that it crashes. Logcat needed here.

Comment: If he creates adapter using app context, it can be cause of problem.

Comment: I've tried. but when I do this new AlertDialog.Builder(NoodnummersActivity.this). It is complaining  ...NoodnummersActivity is not an enclosing class"

Comment: Maybe I should point out that my NoodnummersActivity extends SherlockActivity

Comment: That's the same. :) Try inside to use "context" (now you have the right one). Then tell us!

Answer (score 0):

Use this method for context:

```
private Context getDialogContext() {
        Context context;
        if (getParent() != null)
            context = getParent();
        else
            context = this;
        return context;
    }
```

try this it will work.